# response of a server in python

Tags: ros, rospy, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everybody,

I have a simple question. If I have more than 2 responses in the srv file. How Can I use them in python code. How to use the servicenameResponse() function?

Cheers,

Gauss

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10551/response-of-a-server-in-python/) by [Gauss Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/815/gauss-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-10**:
Can you give an example what you mean with "more than 2 responses". A service consists of 1 request and 1 response per srv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Posting your actual .srv file would help, but I think you just have a bit of terminology issues. If you have two lines in your response section of the service definition, you would have two fields in the response message. For instance, if servicename.srv is:

```
int8 someRequestStuff
---
int8 firstThingToReturn
int8 secondThingToReturn
```

In this case, you could:

```
resp = servicenameResponse()
resp.firstThingToReturn = 1
resp.secondThingToReturn = 2
return resp
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6